# Redux Thunk Callback after dispatching an action?

Tags: reactjs, callback, redux, redux-thunk

So in my React component, I have this:

```
this.props.updateAlertCallback('error', ERROR_MESSAGE)
```

My `updateAlertCallback` action is:

```
export const updateAlert = (alert, message) => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_ALERT',
    alert,
    message
  }
}

export const updateAlertCallback = (alert, message) => {
  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch(updateAlert(alert, message)).then(() => {
      console.log('Done!');
    });
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function**

What's the proper way to log something after `updateAlert` is done running?

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this. To begin with, it isn't clear what you're trying to accomplish. Also, you assign `data` and then immediately check if it's truthy. It always is since you just assigned it. Then`updateAlert` doesn't return anything. It should return an action, or if you need redux thunk for something, it should return a function.

Comment: I also notice you're calling a callback function but because all your code is synchronous (you're not waiting for anything) there is no need for a callback at all.

Comment: hey @DDS, I went ahead and updated the question with my latest situation. I was trying to initiate a callback from my React component after calling this.props.updateAlert instead of initiating a callback in the action.  I think i'm getting closer - do you have any ideas with this updated code?

Comment: Why do you need a callback?

Comment: The proper way to call a function after `updateAlert` is done running is: `this.props.updateAlert('hi'); theFunction();` Just run it after you call it.

Comment: Your edits were not able to clarify what you're trying to accomplish. I have vaguely gathered you want to show an alert and then delete it afterwards or somesuch. It isn't at all clear where you want to go and without that it isn't possible to help you get there.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. Yeah after my alert is updated, I want it to fade out after 5 or so seconds. I will have another action to remove the alert, so I will have to dispatch the DELETE_ALERT action.

Comment: I also commented on your gist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function showAlert(message) {
  return {
    type: SHOW_ALERT, 
    message
  };
}

function hideAlert(message) {
  return {
    type: HIDE_ALERT,
  };
}

function flashAlert(message) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(showAlert(message));
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(hideAlert());
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

You'll need redux-thunk for this to work. You can then use `this.props.flashAlert('Oh noes!!!!')` with the proper `mapStateToProps`. Also needed are reducers and react components.

Fading isn't necessarily an easy thing to do in react. I suggest you save that for later.

What the `flashAlert` function does is it returns a function that takes a `dispatch` function. This function does all kinds of fun things but not yet. First this function gets passed to redux's dispatch. This dispatch would normally throw because actions must be plain objects. But because you're using redux-thunk it will be fine. Redux-thunk will call this function and pass it the `dispatch` function from redux. Now the function will run, finally. First thing it does is dispatch an action that it gets by calling `showAlert()`. This time it's an object with a `type` property, which makes it a proper redux action. Presumably redux will pass this action on to our reducer which will update the state with the new message, but we don't know that for sure because the reducer was left out of this answer for brevity. Who know what code it contains. After the state was changed to show the message somehow, we do a `setTimeout()`. When this calls back we dispatch another action we get by calling `hideAlert()` using the same `dispatch` function we used previously. We still have it. This presumably will scrub the message from the state.

Redux will tell react to rerender the appropriate components whenever the state changes. Presumably one of those components will display or not display the message as the case may be.

Comment: Thank you @DDS! I don't know if you saw, but I commented back to you on my gist, where I basically just called the setTimeout right after I called the showAlert prop in my component. Is it more appropriate to still use redux-thunk and have the timeout after showAlert gets dispatched in this action? Just thinking in terms of best practices at this point, since they both get the job done.

Comment: Using redux-thunk is cleaner. It packages the intent and makes it reusable. Also, make sure you delete the previous alert, if there was one. Otherwise, if two alerts are fired within 5 seconds, the second alert will be closed by the first `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 7):

With redux-thunk, you can make action return a promise:

```
export const updateAlert = (alert, message) => (dispatch, getState) => {  
  dispatch ({
    type: 'UPDATE_ALERT',
    alert,
    message
  });
  return Promise.resolve(getState());
  // or just Promise.resolve();
```

now you can call updateAlert(xx, xx).then(newState => {.....});

Comment: Did you mean `dispatch` in the second line instead of return

Comment: @Swapnil, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Redux-thunk is your answer. In your store code change

```
const enhancers = compose(
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
);
```

to

```
const enhancers = compose(
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

and you will be able to use thunks with your redux actions.

Refer to https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#installation

Comment: Thanks John. What is it that i'm doing wrong? Here's a gist of what I've been trying: https://gist.github.com/drewrawitz/231ccc56bd442dae0ce009d23cd28373

Comment: Never mind, the issue was with my store. The middleware was never being called. I edited the original question with my new store that ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

Actions in redux are plain objects. Redux thunk allows to return functions instead of objects. These functions are executed by the thunk middleware, and ultimately the final object that reaches the store for dispatch is a plain object. An example of redux thunked action is below.

```
export default class AccountActions {

  static login(username, password) {
    return (dispatch, getStore) => {
      dispatch(AccountActions.loginRequest(username));
      fetch(apiUrls.signInUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          user: {
            email: username,
            password: password,
          }
        })
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json().then(responseJson => {
          return dispatch(AccountActions.loginResponse(username, responseJson.token, response.status));
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    };
  }

  static loginRequest(username) {
    return {
      type: ActionTypes.loginRequest,
      username,
    };
  }

  static loginResponse(username, token, status) {
    return {
      type: ActionTypes.loginResponse,
      username,
      token,
      status,
    };
  }

}
```